# Создание окон в среде MFC

Tags: mfc, c++

Продолжаю разбираться в MFC...

- Если не сложно объясните в чём особенность, преимущества создания окна в следующих способах:

1)

```
  void CMy354App::OnButton32771() 
  {
      CMainFrame* pFrame = STATIC_DOWNCAST(CMainFrame, m_pMainWnd);
      pFrame->CreateNewChild(RUNTIME_CLASS(CNewChild), IDR_MY354TYPE, NULL, NULL);
  }
```

2)

```
  void CMy354App::OnButton32771() 
  {
          CNewChild *pFrame=new CNewChild;
          pFrame->LoadFrame(IDR_MY354TYPE);
  }
```

- Если во втором случае окну послать сообщение `WM_CLOSE`, объект класса будет удалён из системы и выделенная память будет автоматически высвобождена?
- `DECLARE_DYNCREATE` - MSDN пишет:

> The framework uses this ability to create new objects dynamically. For
>   example, the new view created when you open a new document. Document,
>   view, and frame classes should support dynamic creation because the
>   framework needs to create them dynamically.

А я разве не динамически создаю объект оператором `new` без всяких `DECLARE_DYNCREATE` ?

Comment: MFC? Оно ж вроде deprecated уже, ну по крайней мере в VS2012. Разрешите полюбопытствовать, на кой вам понадоиблось изучать технологию такой давности?

Comment: @SoloMio А что на ваш взгляд актуально для оконных приложение на C++? DotNet мне не по душе!

Comment: @rejie, Мне кажется, QT или WPF. Но WPF это тот же дот нет.

Comment: @SoloMio, не могли бы вы дать ссылку на документ, в котором говорится, что MFC deprecated в 2012?

Answer (score 1):

C) Посмотрите как описан макрос `DECLARE_DYNCREATE`. Он создает статический метод `CreateObject`. А его имплементация - `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE`. При `new CNewChild` вы явно указываете тип.